# Loading an xml document from string throws the exception "'1.0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following string used in C# code

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-16?>
<identity xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
<name>sam</name>
</identity>
```

trying to load this using LoadXml() throws the following error

'1.0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''

I have no control over the string used in LoadXml() and cant change it.How do I solve this?

Comment: Contact whoever is generating the xml for you, it's appears to be invalid.

Comment: or remove the first line youself (programaticly)

Comment: I would be *very* nervous of any "nearly XML" document you end up with which is invalid. It suggests it was produced by hand instead of via an XML API, so it could easily have all kinds of issues.

Comment: Is it because there are no quotes.I have posted the xml only partially here.Removing the first line,throws up similar errors in subsequent lines.Is it because """ are missing?

Comment: Yes, XML Attributes must be quoted, otherwise it's not valid XML.

Comment: oh thats bad :(..seems like i shud start pointing finger at someone now..Thanks for the replies guys..i thot there wud be some magical way to solve this.

Comment: Just out of interest, where is this XML coming from - is it being supplied to you by a 3rd party, or generated by some ERP system, etc?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-attrval `The Name in the start- and end-tags gives the element's type. [Definition: The Name-AttValue pairs are referred to as the attribute specifications of the element], [Definition: with the Name in each pair referred to as the attribute name ] and [Definition: the content of the AttValue **(the text between the ' or " delimiters)** as the attribute value.] Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.`

Comment: @asawyer thanks...since the xml came from an already deployed system,i doudbted my basics :)

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan When in doubt, refer to the specifications! :)

Comment: @StephenByrne its being provided by 3rd party.so i cant touch it.only just keep whining

Comment: :( Best of luck with it!

Comment: @StephenByrne thanks..parsing it using code